# Missing $, { and } in a table with mixed numbers and text

Tags: tables, math-mode

Is my first time here so i'm gonna try to write a good question. I must write a table several times in my latex document and I get a warning about a missing $, { and }.

The reduced version of the table is:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Stellar parameters of G 160-62}
\label{table:}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\hline\hline  \noalign{\vskip 0.7mm}
Parameter \hspace{0.0 mm}& Value & Reference \\
\hline \noalign{\vskip 0.7mm}
    $L_\star$ $(L_{\odot})$ & 0.0761 \pm 0.0014 & Cif20\\
\hline \noalign{\vskip 0.7mm}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

And my used packages are:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={150mm,247mm},
 left=30mm,
 top=30mm,
 }
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
```

Where should be the $, { and }?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always helps to provide a complete test document not fragments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={150mm,247mm},
 left=30mm,
 top=30mm,
 }
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Stellar parameters of G 160-62}
\label{table:}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\hline\hline  \noalign{\vskip 0.7mm}
Parameter \hspace{0.0 mm}& Value & Reference \\
\hline \noalign{\vskip 0.7mm}
    $L_\star$ $(L_{\odot})$ & 0.0761 \pm 0.0014 & Cif20\\
\hline \noalign{\vskip 0.7mm}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Produces the error

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.24     $L_\star$ $(L_{\odot})$ & 0.0761 \pm
                                              0.0014 & Cif20\\
?
```

Note this is at `\pm` which is a math mode command add `$`  and it runs without error:

```
    $L_\star$ $(L_{\odot})$ & $0.0761 \pm 0.0014$ & Cif20\\
```

Comment: Works! Thank you so much for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

There is `$` around `\pm` missing.

See the following corrected MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={150mm,247mm},
 left=30mm,
 top=30mm,
 }
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Stellar parameters of G 160-62}
\label{table:}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\hline\hline  \noalign{\vskip 0.7mm}
Parameter \hspace{0.0 mm}& Value & Reference \\
\hline \noalign{\vskip 0.7mm}
    $L_{\star} (L_{\odot})$ & 0.0761 $\pm$ 0.0014 & Cif20\\
    %                                ^   ^ <============================
\hline \noalign{\vskip 0.7mm}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]